# rails alternative name for association one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

Simply i have table

```
[product_categories]
name
```

and

```
[products]
category_id
name
```

if i use in product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :...
belongs_to :product_category
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :...
  set_table_name "product_categories"

  has_many :products
end
```

i can fire

```
product = Product.new
product.product_category
```

but it is possible to rename that product_category for association for example

```
product.category
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to refer to the category with `product.product_category` and want to use only `product.category` do:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :...
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ProductCategory'
end
```